# Is there a better way to create a dynamic match on mongo?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm in the process of creating a view which shows all types of data.  Currently I'm using tons of if statements to true and create a match parameter for all the different type of request.  I really don't think writing out 120 possible if statements is the best way.. plus its getting hard to keep off.  I'm hoping someone can point in the right direction.  This is what I have so far.

```
func GetAllHourly(dbsession *mgo.Session, year, month, day, site, size, network, region string, code int) (items []MassAggregation, err error) {
    defer dbsession.Close()
    var match bson.M
    if network == "openx3" {
        network = "openx"
    }

    group := bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"aws_region": "$aws_region", "http_request_status": "$http_request_status", "hour": "$hour", "network": "$network", "site": "$site", "size": "$size", "zone": "$zone", "extra": "$extra"}, "total": bson.M{"$sum": "$count"}}}
    if site == "" && size == "" && network == "" && region == "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day}}
    } else if site != "" && size == "" && network == "" && region == "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site}}
    } else if site != "" && size != "" && network == "" && region == "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "size": size}}
    } else if site != "" && size != "" && network != "" && region == "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "size": size, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}}}
    } else if site != "" && size != "" && network != "" && region != "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "size": size, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "aws_region": region}}
    } else if site != "" && size != "" && network != "" && region != "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "size": size, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "aws_region": region, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site == "" && size != "" && network == "" && region == "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "size": size}}
    } else if site == "" && size != "" && network != "" && region == "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "size": size, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}}}
    } else if site == "" && size != "" && network != "" && region != "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "size": size, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "aws_region": region}}
    } else if site == "" && size == "" && network != "" && region == "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}}}
    } else if site == "" && size == "" && network != "" && region != "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "aws_region": region}}
    } else if site == "" && size == "" && network != "" && region != "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "aws_region": region, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site == "" && size == "" && network == "" && region != "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "aws_region": region}}
    } else if site == "" && size == "" && network == "" && region != "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "aws_region": region, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site == "" && size == "" && network == "" && region == "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site != "" && size == "" && network == "" && region == "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site != "" && size == "" && network == "" && region != "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "aws_region": region}}
    } else if site != "" && size == "" && network != "" && region == "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}}}
    } else if site == "" && size != "" && network == "" && region == "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "size": size, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site == "" && size != "" && network == "" && region != "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "size": size, "aws_region": region}}
    } else if site == "" && size != "" && network != "" && region == "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "size": size, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}}}
    } else if site == "" && size == "" && network != "" && region == "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site == "" && size == "" && network != "" && region != "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "aws_region": region}}
    } else if site != "" && size != "" && network != "" && region == "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "size": size, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site != "" && size != "" && network == "" && region == "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "site": site, "size": size, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site == "" && size != "" && network != "" && region == "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "size": size, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site != "" && size == "" && network != "" && region != "" && code == -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "aws_region": region, "site": site}}
    } else if site != "" && size == "" && network != "" && region != "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "aws_region": region, "site": site, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site != "" && size == "" && network == "" && region != "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "aws_region": region, "site": site, "http_request_status": code}}
    } else if site == "" && size != "" && network != "" && region != "" && code != -1 {
        match = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day, "network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}, "aws_region": region, "size": size, "http_request_status": code}}
    }

    operations := []bson.M{match, group}
    err = dbsession.DB("logs").C("prod").Pipe(operations).All(&items)
    return
}
```

As you can see it's unruly.. but i haven't found an alternative yet.  I'm hoping I just haven't found the answer.

**UPDATE:**  I've changed my approach a bit.  I'm still curious if this is the best way.

```
func GetAllHourly(dbsession *mgo.Session, year, month, day, site, size, network, region string, code int) (items []MassAggregation, err error) {
    defer dbsession.Close()
    matches := []bson.M{bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"year": year, "month": month, "day": day}}}
    if network == "openx3" {
        network = "openx"
    }

    if site != "" {
        matches = append(matches, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"site": site}})
    }
    if size != "" {
        matches = append(matches, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"size": size}})
    }
    if region != "" {
        matches = append(matches, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"aws_region": region}})
    }
    if code != -1 {
        matches = append(matches, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"http_request_status": code}})
    }
    if network != "" {
        matches = append(matches, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"network": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: network, Options: "i"}}})
    }
    group := bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"aws_region": "$aws_region", "http_request_status": "$http_request_status", "hour": "$hour", "network": "$network", "site": "$site", "size": "$size", "zone": "$zone", "extra": "$extra"}, "total": bson.M{"$sum": "$count"}}}
    var operations []bson.M
    for _, match := range matches {
        operations = append(operations, match)
    }
    operations = append(operations, group)
    err = dbsession.DB("logs").C("prod").Pipe(operations).All(&items)
    return
}
```

Comment: I never expect `go` to be a typing friendly programming language. Someone call it a `if err!=nil` language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bson.M{}` is just named type for `map[string]interface{}` as you can see in docs: http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M

So, why don't you just use it as dictionary to build custom query? You'll have much less code:

```
query := bson.M{}

if site != "" {
       query["site"] = site
    }
    if size != "" {
       query["size"] = size
    }

}

// Then use query variable for querying mongodb
```

Comment: Im aware, so then my second try is optimal in terms logic?  Switching over to a map string wouldn't change the logic or remove the if statements. What i want to know is if there is a way to match better. Lets say i have 20 toggles. Would i really have to write 20 if statements?

Comment: You can't  avoid business logic, so you must use if/switch statement. But you still can write less code to minimize future pain of understanding for you and your colleagues. Moreover, you need to have similar code in an SearchModel structure in an Validate() method to validate data received from user. Next level of optimizing code readability, maintenance and security, instead passing search parameters as function arguments, create structure with this fields, and then pass it to function:

 func GetAllHourly(dbsession *mgo.Session, SearchModel search) (items []MassAggregation, err error) {